# Questions about connecting ADS1115 for voltage measurement

Tags: voltage-divider, measurement, voltage-measurement

Purpose: to measure the voltage on the DC bus (about 600VDC).

ADS1115 [Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1115.pdf?ts=1691024879228&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FADS1115)

I looked at the use cases and saw two connection options (in the first case, we use two inputs, in the second, only one).
P.s. additional protective elements in the form of a diode at the input are not indicated here.

A:
[image]
B:
[image]

**Questions:**

1. What connection scheme should I use in my case?
2. If it is necessary to use a two-input circuit, is there a polarity? (In terms of A0 necessarily between the resistors, A1 to ground).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's little to no need for a differential connection (first schematic), but you can configure the inputs to use 1] as 2] so there's nothing lost in wiring it that way.

With a 3.6kΩ resistor there's not much, if any, measurable improvement with a Kelvin connection. 3600/2^15 = 0.1Ω, which is several cm of even a 0.005" (0.127mm) trace, so layout has only a small effect.

[image]

You would normally connect AIN0 to the more positive voltage if using the differential connection, but it will work either way (you'll get a negative reading if AIN1 > AIN0) provided that both AIN0 and AIN0 are >= 0.

Comment: Now everything is clear. Thank you very much for your answer! Issue resolved.